# Show that function is discontinuous at every point and that derivative doesn't exist

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I want to show that the function is discontinuous at every point $x\neq 0$ and that derivative doesn't exist. With discontinuity I have no problem. So let

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be defined by $f(x):=x^2$ if $x$ is rational, and $f(x):=0$ if $x$ is irrational.

**Proof of discontinuity:**

Let $x \in \mathbb Q$. Then there exists a sequnce $(x_n) \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ with $\lim(x_n)=x$. Then we have $f(x)=x^2\neq0 =f(x_n)$

Let $x \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$. Then there exists a sequence $(x_n) \in \mathbb Q$ with $\lim(x_n)=x$. Then we have $f(x)=0 \neq x^2=f(x_n)$. So we can conclude, than $f$ is diccontinuous at every point $x\neq 0$.

**Questions:**

1. Can somebody show me, how can we prove the discontinuity with $\delta-\epsilon$ definition?
2. How can we show that derivative doesn't exist with definition (not just say discontinuous implies derivative doesn't exist)

Thank you for help!

Comment: Discontinuous implies derivative does not exists is not  a statement taken for granted. You can assume that the derivative exists at a point and show that it is continuous at that point and hence derive a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Question**

Let $x\neq 0$ and let $x\in\Bbb{Q}\cap(0,1)$ . Then $ 0<r<x<1$ for some positive $r\in \Bbb{R}$ .

Then let $\epsilon=r^{2}$ and let $\delta>0$ be any positive number.

Then pick an irrational  number $p$ in $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$.

Then $|f(p)-f(x)|=|0-x^{2}|\geq r^{2}=\epsilon$ which contradicts continuity . Similarly do it for $x\in(-1,0)\cap\Bbb{Q}$

For $|x|\geq 1$ and $x$ rational, we have for any delta, we find an irrational $p\in (x-\delta,x+\delta)$ such that $|f(p)-f(x)|=|x^{2}|\geq 1$ which is not possible for $\epsilon=1$.

Do the same for when $x$ is irrational and $|x|<1$ and $|x|\geq 1$ similarly. (Everything will be same except we find a rational number $p$ in such $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$.

**Second Question**

We look at the expression $\displaystyle D:=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ .

If $x\in\Bbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$ then for a sequence of irrationals $h_{n}\to 0$ we have $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^{2}}{h_{n}}$ which does not exist.

If $x\in\Bbb{R}\setminus\Bbb{Q}$ then  Now for any $\delta>0$ we have for a rational in $q$ in $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$, that $|\displaystyle \frac{f(q)-f(x)}{q-x}|=|\frac{q^{2}}{q-x}|\geq \frac{q^{2}}{\delta}$ . Which means that as $\delta$ becomes smaller ($q\to x$), the expression becomes unbounded and hence limit cannot exist.

If $x=0$ . Then $|\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}|\leq \frac{\max(h^{2},0)}{h}\leq |h|$. And hence the derivative at $0$ exists and is equal to $0$.

Comment: +1 for having an epic name.

Comment: Thank you! It was helpful

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thanks. But it was created in the spur of the moment and makes no actual sense really. I mean why would Gandlaf have his last name as Sauron. Even Saruman would have made more sense.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron I completely agree that it does not make any sense. The funny part for me was that you decided to go with the modest "Mr." after combining two of the most powerful characters of Middle Earth.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron sorry one question more. In first question you wrote that $r>\lvert x \rvert$ but $\lvert f(p)-f(x)=\lvert 0-x^2 \rvert \geq r^2$ how is it possible? If $r> \lvert x \rvert$ then $\lvert x^2 \rvert \geq r^2$ is impossible. Is it mistake or my missunderstanding?

Comment: Oops sorry mistake in sign of the inequality. You're correct. I'll edit it